# Detect how vim was quit in autocommand

Tags: autocmd, quit

I have an autocommand on ExitPre like this:

```
autocmd ExitPre * call PromptSaveSession()
```

I'd like to avoid prompting to save the session if vim was forcefully exited, e.g. ':q!' or ':qa!'.

Is there a way I can detect if the command used to exit vim was followed by a bang? I tried:

```
autocmd ExitPre * call PromptSaveSession(<bang>)
```

This produced an error on exit (as expected). I also tried reading the value of `v:cmdbang`, but it's always 0 regardless of the command used to exit.

Comment: Can you tell us more about this function? Why not just use Vim's prompt (enabled with `:set confirm`) that, for example, `:q` triggers when called with a modified buffer?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's XY problem. You're trying to develop some sort of KISS tool for semi-auto session tracking (and that's a right decision, IMO). But for some reason you're trying to induce dependency on the "quit command". And this is plainly wrong. Whatever the last command was, Vim should just quit. Think of another way to track session state.

Comment: @Matt Ah, you're thinking of "session" like `:mks` kind of session. I was thinking of the term generically...you're probably right...which means my suggestion is not very useful. :P

Comment: @BLayer @Matt right, `PromptSaveSession` prompts the user if they want to save the session and then calls `:mks`. The problem I'm trying to fix is if the user hits `Esc` or `Ctrl-C` to cancel, instead of entering Y or N at the prompt, vim immediately exits. This seems unfriendly to me as a user.

Comment: Honestly, it all sounds to me as a poor design. I don't really like asking a user (me!) so many hard questions every time. If I only could mention my own solution here: test `:h v:this_session` upon `VimLeave` and if it's not empty then `mks!` it. After all, in 99% cases when I've loaded the session I want to update it too. As for 1% I don't mind doing `:let v:this_session=""` manually before quitting.